# Looking for a way to view lines of a text file one-at-a-time centered on screen

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, text-processing

I'm looking for a way to take a text file and put each line one-at-a-time centered on screen with a certain character width.

Sort of like a bare-bones slide show, e.g. seeing the first line until the user presses a key, and then seeing the next line, until all the lines have been viewed.

I suspect there is a basic way to do this in bash, but I haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this gist https://gist.github.com/rhowardiv/3860861

Comment: this script https://github.com/visit1985/mdp

Comment: ok, and why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: a few other things I found on github, I'll see if I can find them again, basically it was all overkill for what I was trying to do

Comment: These all require a markup language or special formatting, I'm hoping to find a solution for just lines of a text file

Comment: also tried - https://github.com/ryanuber/slide.sh

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! "$#" -eq 1 ]
then
    printf "Usage: %s <file>\n" "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi

file="$1"

display_center(){
    clear
    columns="$(tput cols)"
    lines="$(tput lines)"
    down=$((lines / 2))
    printf '\n%.0s' $(seq 1 $down)
    printf "%*s\n" $(( (${#1} + columns) / 2)) "$1"
}

while IFS= read -r line
do
    display_center "$line"
    read -n 1 -s -r </dev/tty
done < "$file"
```

Name it `centered.sh` and use like that:

```
./centered.sh centered.sh
```

It will print each line from the given file. Press any key to show the
next line. Notice that it's not well tested yet so use with caution
and that it'll always print lines starting from the center of the screen so it will
make long lines appear more at the bottom.

The first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

is a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).
Additionally, I use `env` for [its
features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612980/why-is-usr-bin-env-bash-superior-to-bin-bash).
I tried to avoid Bash and write this script in POSIX shell but I gave up because especially `read` was very problematic.  You should keep in
mind that even though it may seem that Bash is ubiquitous it isn't
preset everywhere by default, for example on BSD or small embedded
systems with Busybox.

In this part:

```
if [ ! "$#" -eq 1 ]
then
    printf "Usage: %s <file>\n" "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

we check if user provided exactly one parameter and if they didn't we print
usage info to standard error and return 1, that means an error to
a parent process.

Here

```
file="$1"
```

we assign filename parameter that user has passed to a variable
`file` that we'll use later.

This is a function that actually prints centered text:

```
display_center(){
    clear
    columns="$(tput cols)"
    lines="$(tput lines)"
    down=$((lines / 2))
    printf '\n%.0s' $(seq 1 $down)
    printf "%*s\n" $(( (${#1} + columns) / 2)) "$1"
}
```

There are no function prototypes in Bash so you can't know how many
parameters function takes in advance - that one takes only one
parameter which is a line to print and it's dereferenced using `$1` This functions first clears the
screen, then moves down by lines/2 from the top of the screen to reach
center of the screen and then it prints centered line using the method
I borrowed from [here](https://superuser.com/a/829870/328038).

That is the loop that reads input file passed by the user and calls
`display_center()` function:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    display_center "$line"
    read -n 1 -s -r </dev/tty
done < "$file"
```

`read` is used with `-n 1` to read only one character, `-s` to not
echo input coming from a terminal and `-r` to [prevent mangling
backslashes](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2162).  You
can learn more about `read` in `help read`.  We also read from
/dev/tty directly because stdin already points to the file - if we
didn't tell `read` to read from /dev/tty the script would very quickly
print all lines from the file and exit immediately without waiting for
the user to press a key.

Comment: Awesome, couldn't be better. I'll have to review your code to learn more about how you did it. Would you mind posting a few sentences summarizing your approach for someone new to bash? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `dialog` package:

```
file=lorem                             #Path to the file to be displayed
ln=1                                   #Current line number to be displayed
nlines=$(wc -l "$file"|cut -f1 -d" ")  #Total number of lines of file
while [ "$ln" -le "$nlines" ]; do
    line=$(sed -n "$ln p" "$file")     #sed gets current line
    if dialog --yes-label Previous --no-label Next \
    --default-button no --yesno "$line" 5 100; then
        ln=$((ln-1))
    else
        ln=$((ln+1))
    fi
done
```

It is a text-based presentation (I took "bare-bones slide show" seriously!), no X session required, that displays one line at a time. You can go backwards or forwards and it ends after the last line.

Comment: I like this answer but I'm going to accept the other one because it has no dependencies and has a more minimal visual. Thanks so much for your time, and for teaching me about the dialog package! Very cool stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick'n'dirty one-liner:

```
sed ':a;s/^.\{1,77\}$/ &/;ta;s/\( *\)\1/\1/; s/.*/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n&\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n/' < input.txt | more
```

This assumes an 80x24 terminal window.  The `sed` command centers each line of text, then adds enough leading and trailing newlines to vertically center.  The `more` command allows the user to page through.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the idea!